# My dropdown menu is hidden by my partial template in Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I was able to build my first veterinarian Angular app with three partial templates and a dropdown menu using tutorials and SO's community great feedback, so I am very happy! :)

Intro page:

[image]

However, when I select "employees", I get my whisker box plots that block the dropdown menu:

[image]

I assume it's a matter of CSS, but I have been stuck for quite a while and would greatly appreciate the community's feedback.

Moreover, if I may ask, how could I have the menu button on the far right, same height as the topBanner with the dropdown menu aligned with the right edge (instead of the left edge as shown)? Thank you very much!

My webform:

```
...
<body onload="loadPikaday()" data-ng-app="myModule">

    <%-- Header --%>
    <div id="topBanner" class="topBanner">
        <div id="menu" class="menu">
            Report from: &emsp; 
            <input id="startDate" size="6" type="text" data-ng-model="startDate" /> &emsp; To &emsp; 
            <input id="endDate" size="6" type="text" data-ng-model="endDate" />&emsp; 

           <%-- Dropdown menu --%>
            <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">MENU</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#/cases">Cases</a>
                    <a href="#/protocols">Protocols</a>
                    <a href="#/employees">Employees</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

    <%-- Where html is injected--%>
    <div id="currentPage" class="currentPage">
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <%-- Footer  --%>
    <div id="footer" class="footer">Veterinary Application</div>
</body>
...
```

my CSS file:

```
body,html{ 
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.topBanner{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
}

.menu{
    text-align: left; 
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
}

#startDate, #endDate{
    font-size: 40px;
}

#button{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.currentPage{
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
    text-align: center; 
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

Comment: seems like a simple css `z-index` problem

Comment: z-index? Ok! I will look into it! Thank you!